# Unable to get Value against the key in the dictionary python

Tags: python, string, dataframe, dictionary

[this is my dictionary with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oatt5.png)I have two dataframes A & B having one column in common of type string (str) i.e. country_name

I converted `dataframe B` into a dictionary object which has only two columns of string type. that means both key and value columns are of string type.

My task is to find the value based on the key from the `dataframe B`. The key belongs to `dataframe A` since I have a common column.

Here is my code...

I have tried multiple options but nothing works for me like

```
name = count_list.get(key, "")
name = count_list['Value'][key]
```

---

```
A= pd.DataFrame(columns:{'index','name','score'})
B= pd.DataFrame(columns:{'name','Value'})

B= B.to_dict()

for index, row in A.iterrows():
    try:
       key = str(row['name']).lower()
       name = B.get(key, "")
       score1.append(row['score'])
       country_list.append(name)
   except TypeError:
       print(row)
   except IndexError:
       print(row)
```

I want to get the exact value against a key in the data frame B.
both key and Value columns are of string type.

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me.

Comment: what exactly you want to ask ?